# Tomando como base las reglas de cardinalidad en una base de datos, ¿En que tablas deberían estar ubicadas las llaves foráneas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy un programador principiante de clase junior, estoy muy interesado en el tema así que por eso hago esta pregunta. Siempre eh tenido la duda de donde deberían ubicarse las llaves foráneas ya sea en una relacion de 1:1, 1:n o n:m.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado o leido al respecto?

Comment: No mucho ,tengo entendido que: en una relacion de 1:1 ,no importa quien se lleve la llave foranea, en una relacion de 1:n se lo llevaría la primera de estas y en una de n:m se crea una nueva tabla donde se almacena las llaves foraneas, solo deseo ser despejado de esa duda, si se me puede proporcionar de alguna dirección url con la información que deseo también será de gran ayuda.

Comment: Claro que si importa donde queda la llave foránea, lee esto: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-types-of-relations/